# In Python, I get a NameError for a variable that I previously defined when I set it to 2

Tags: python

I'm running into a NameError in Python when I'm processing a variable that is equal to 2. It's telling me that my variable is undefined.

I set the variable to an empty tuple and I gave it a value of one. When it had a value of one it worked properly but whenever I put two in there is gives me a blank answer (the empty tuple).

I apologize if this is a silly question, I haven't been practicing Python for very long. Thanks for your time.

Here's the code for the part of the program I'm struggling with:

```
character = input("What character are you saving for? ")
phaseout = int(input("What phase is " + character + " coming out in? (1 or 2): "))
currentphase = int(input("Current phase (1 or 2): "))
daysleftinphase = int(input("Days left in current phase: "))

# phase calculations
# does NOT include the 20 days for the phase the desired character is out
phasedays = ('')
if currentphase == 1:
  if phaseout == 1:
    phasedays = 20 + daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 1:
  if phaseout == 2:
    phasedays = 40 + daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 2:
  if phaseout == 1:
    phasedays = daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 2:
  if phaseout == 2:
    phasedays = 20 + daysleftinphase

print("\nDays you'll have when it comes to phases:", phasedays)
```

Whenever I answer "What phase is " + character + " coming out in? (1 or 2): " with 2, that's where my issue lies. I get the empty tuple (and with no empty tuple I get the name error, telling me phasedays isn't defined).

Entire error message with no empty tuple for backup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
        print("\nDays you'll have when it comes to phases:", phasedays)
NameError: name 'phasedays' is not defined
```

Comment: Let's start with something simple: there are no tuples here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: I don't get any error when I run your code. But there is a bug: you have the same condition repeated in the `if` and one of the `elif`s. Only the body after the first condition to evaluate to True will execute.

Comment: To see this in action, you can add more `print()` statements to each `if` or `elif` block to see what executes. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more tips on debugging your code.

Comment: The code you posted here does NOT cuase the error you show. Please check that the code you see here matches what you are running on your computer.

Comment: Follow your code logic carefully: if `currentphase` is 1 and `phaseout` is not 1, you don't (re-)assign anything to `phasedays`.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that will induce a NameError exception. The variable *phasedays* is assigned an empty string after all inputs have been called. It may not be modified in any of the if/elif conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As joanis hinted to in the comment, once you enter an `if` or `elseif` clause, no other `else` or `elseif` clause in the same `if`/`elseif`/`else` structure will be evaluated. In particular, if you have two clauses with the same condition, if the condition is true, you will always end up in the first one; the second one will never be evaluated. Thus, to do what you want, you need to test both conditions at the same time.

```
if currentphase == 1 and phaseout == 1:
    phasedays = 20 + daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 1 and phaseout == 2:
    phasedays = 40 + daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 2 and phaseout == 1:
    phasedays = daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 2 and phaseout == 2:
    phasedays = 20 + daysleftinphase
```

Alternately, and more efficiently, you can make sure each branch is complete, and you don't have repeated conditions.

```
if currentphase == 1:
  if phaseout == 1:
    phasedays = 20 + daysleftinphase
  elif phaseout == 2:
    phasedays = 40 + daysleftinphase
elif currentphase == 2:
  if phaseout == 1:
    phasedays = daysleftinphase
  elif phaseout == 2:
    phasedays = 20 + daysleftinphase
```

Even better, particularly in your case, you could use a lookup dictionary, and use tuples as an index:

```
days_to_add_lookup = {
    (1, 1): 20,
    (1, 2): 40,
    (2, 1): 0,
    (2, 2): 20,
}
days_to_add = days_to_add_lookup[(currentphase, phaseout)]
phasedays = daysleftinphase + days_to_add
```